# How to add images to Tkinter GUI on Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Background information so you can understand why I asked this question:

- The version of Python I use is 3.7
- I am a student
- In my class, we started learning Python 2 months ago
- The start of this class was the first time I encountered Python
- You may take it as me having almost zero knowledge of this language.

Anyway,

I tried coding multiple images into one frame in a project I was doing that uses a Tkinter GUI. However, the error message:

'_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "snake1.jpg": no such file or directory'

comes out whenever I try to run the program, although I have already ensured that all images I plan to use was placed within the same directory as my project, and also made sure that there were no typos and errors when I try to call the file.

I think there was something wrong with what I put in, but according to the reference material I am using, it seems to have no errors.

In the directory, the files are in the folders as follows:

C:\Users\[my account name]\PycharmProjects\Practice Coding\GUI Practice

GUI Practice contains:
Practice_GUI_Game.py, 
snake1.jpg, 
snake2.jpg, 
snake3.jpg, 
snake4.jpg.

Please look over the code and tell me what I did wrong. All answers will be noted and appreciated. Thank you.

```
    from tkinter import *

    game = Tk()
    game.wm_title("Snake Collection")
    game.config(bg="#EB5E55")

    left1 = Frame(game, width=500, height=1000)
    left1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    def bonuslvl():
        bonusimg1 = PhotoImage(file='snake1.jpg')
        Label(left1, image=bonusimg1).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        bonusimg2 = PhotoImage(file='snake2.jpg')
        Label(left1, image=bonusimg2).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        bonusimg3 = PhotoImage(file='snake3.jpg')
        Label(left1, image=bonusimg3).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        bonusimg4 = PhotoImage(file='snake4.jpg')
        Label(left1, image=bonusimg4).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    bonuslvl()

    game.mainloop()
```

After changing the names of each jpeg image to something else, then returning them to the original name, I encountered a new error:

```
      File "C:\Users\[my account name]\PycharmProjects\Practice Coding\GUI  Practice\Practice_GUI_Game.py", line 10, in bonuslvl
          bonusimg1 = PhotoImage(file='snake1.jpg')       
      File "C:\Users\[my account name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3542, in __init__
          Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\[my account name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3498, in __init__
          self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)         
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "snake1.jpg"

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your images need to be in the same directory as the python script you're trying to run.

Comment: They are in the same directory. I even made a separate directory from my other projects that contains the photos AND the script in a single folder.

Comment: Can you post the full error log. That would help in debugging.

Comment: Posted it. Can you review it please?

Comment: Okay. So, the recent versions of `tkinter` don't support `jpg`. You can either convert to `png` or use `canvas` or `PIL` for reading images. If you want this code to work as it is downgrade your `tkinter` version.

Comment: how do I use PIL? Do I need to download anything for it to work?

Comment: `pip install Pillow`

Comment: I have updated my answer below. Please let me know if that works. @Denise

Comment: thanks for the answer! Really helped!

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: hi @waqasgard, I accepted the answer, but I can't seem to upvote it. Has something to do with me not having enough 'reputation'. Sorry about that.

Comment: Nevermind! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems tkinter doesn't support `.jpg` anymore.

I solved your problem using PIL.

To install PIL run `pip install Pillow`.

I managed to make it work on my local machine as:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

game = Tk()
game.wm_title("Snake Collection")
game.config(bg="#EB5E55")

left1 = Frame(game, width=500, height=1000)
left1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)

def bonuslvl():

    bonusimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='snake1.jpg')
    Label(left1, image=bonusimg1).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

bonuslvl()

game.mainloop()
```